# Accuracy of OpenGL ES Instrument

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, instruments, frame-rate

I'm developing a game for the iPhone.  I've decided that 30FPS is plenty so I've written some code that only allows the App to present the render buffer every 1/30 of a second.  When I tried to verify this with Instruments I got varying information.

On an iPod Touch (2009 edition, 32G) it reports 30 FPS for Core Animation Frames Per Second.

On an iPhone 3G I get wildly varying results.  And not just less than 30 FPS.  I see >30 FPS on a regular basis.  It actually seems to hang closer to 36-39.

To investigate this anomaly I added my own FPS to the app and update it once per second.  I stays right at 29 FPS on both devices.

So, does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be going on?  I expect Instruments to be accurate so it really concerns me that it appears inaccurate.  It makes me think I have a bug somewhere, but I sure can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using CADisplayLink?  This might give you a little bit more precision on your main loop.